# How to edit quickOSM map presets?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, road, quickosm

I am having issues using the quickOSM urban map preset and was hoping there was someone who could point me in the direction of a different preset or if there is a simple way (I am new to GIS so the simpler the better!) to create a new preset for future use. My issue is when the "25k to 50k" symbol is visible all the roads from the "1:25k" symbol are showing as white lines. I would like some of them visible but not all of them.